# Excel vba: Find a row based on a unique id, pull it, edit it, then import it back to the same spot with revisions

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm working on a large data table in excel and I'm trying to create a new sheet (Sheet2) that uses vba/macros to allow for the manipulation of data in sheet1. I've already created functionality to add a new row to the bottom of the table (see below) but now I'm trying to figure out a way to pull a row, based on its' ID (column A in Sheet1), then have the user edit or revise it, and export it back into Sheet1 in its' original location (I've also attached a picture).

```
Sub Import()
'
' Import Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

copySheet.Range("B7:R7").Copy
With pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

[image: excel_macro_format]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function to find the ID. Once you have the ID, only thing left is to copy from sheet3 to sheet2 and later back to sheet 3. I have implemented functions to find the ID and copy data. The structure for Import and Export are basically same but the copy from and paste to parameters to the functions have interchanged

```
Sub Import()
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim idRow As Integer
    idRow = findId(pasteSheet.Range("C3"))

    If (idRow = 0) Then
        MsgBox ("ID not found")
        End
    End If

    'implement a function that finds the ID and saves the row number in idRow

    Call CopyPaste(copySheet.Range("B" & idRow & ":R" & idRow), _
        pasteSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))

End Sub

Sub Export()
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim idRow As Integer
    idRow = findId(pasteSheet.Range("C3"))

    If (idRow = 0) Then
        MsgBox ("ID not found")
        End
    End If

    'implement a function that finds the ID and saves the row number in idRow

    Call CopyPaste(pasteSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 17), _
        copySheet.Range("B" & idRow & ":R" & idRow))

End Sub

Function findId(ids As String) As Integer
    Dim findRow As Range
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    'Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Select

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Set findRow = Selection.Find(What:=ids, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not findRow Is Nothing Then
        findId = findRow.Row
        Else
        findId = 0
    End If
End Function

Sub CopyPaste(from As Range, copyTo As Range)
    from.Copy Destination:=copyTo
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```